# Is there a way to access and stream one's iTunes music collection from a web browser?

Tags: itunes, streaming, web-browser

Does the possibility exist to access one's iTunes music collection from any web browser? e.g. to browse the library and stream the songs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One possibility :

Moving your iTunes library to your `~/Sites/` directory and enable files sharing.

With this your the content of your library will be accessible from your browser with your ip ( `http://myip/~MyUsername/` )

Answer (score 1):

Use Plex, it's free and awesome. Stream iTunes playlists, stream movies all from your home computer. Tutorials on YouTube.

Answer (score 0):

Found an application that maybe a suitable alternative to Matthieu's answer:

[pulpTunes](http://pulptunes.com/) aka *The Web Server for iTunes*

Allows you to access your music from anywhere via a web browser.

It is available for both OS X and Windows.

Answer (score 0):

Another application that fits the bill is iHomeServer for iTunes - this app generally extends iTunes's media serving capabilities including providing an iTunes web interface.  The web interface is initially only available internally on your home network, however if you register at http://www.StreamMyiTunes.com then you can log in to your home computer's iTunes from anywhere.

Also has a built in DLNA server so I've been able to replace quite a few different programs with just this one.

http://www.bizmodeller.com/iHomeServer/iHomeServer-Access-iTunes-From-The-Internet.aspx