# Is there a web interface for iTunes?

Tags: itunes, music, web-browser

I occasionally purchase songs from Apple via iTunes. I really like this because it gives me access to the physical `.m4a` files that I can manually back up to listen to anywhere, offline, even if my Apple account gets closed or Apple goes bankrupt in the far future.

But iTunes only runs on Windows and macOS, which is a drawback. (I currently keep around a laptop with Windows on it, just for use as an iTunes terminal. But this is a bit annoying when compared with Bandcamp and Amazon MP3, which let me use any standard web browser to download my music.)

So my question is: does Apple offer any access to my (paid) music library’s `.m4a` files from a **standard web browser** such as Firefox or Chrome?

---

### Stuff I already checked

I have already signed in to https://music.apple.com/ and https://beta.music.apple.com/, but I can’t check those since I’m not currently subscribed to Apple Music. (*Does* that site provide `.m4a` downloads if I were to subscribe? I can’t find any clear information confirming or denying this.)

This is not a duplicate of [Is there a way to access and stream one's iTunes music collection from a web browser?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/q/101947/72465) because the Accepted answer (and every other answer) requires either iTunes, Windows, or both; additionally, they don’t actually grant access to the `.m4a` files. I’m asking if there’s any access to the `.m4a` files for a **standard web browser**, not “a web browser *plus* the iTunes desktop client *plus* some 3rd-party server software”.

---

### Clarifications

- I’m not asking for [recommendations for competing music vendors](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/685059) (e.g. CD stores); I already know about those.
- I’m not asking for [recommendations for competing products](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/685061) (e.g. music streaming services); I’m not in the market for those.
- I’m not asking for [recommendations for competing music management software](https://apple.stackexchange.com/posts/comments/685079); once I actually *have* the `.m4a` files, I will manage them myself.

I’m only asking whether I can download `.m4a` files from Apple with a **standard web browser**, or if dedicated software like the iTunes Desktop Client is required.

---

If there really is **no** authorized way to download my paid library’s `.m4a` files with a standard web browser, I would also be interested to know that.

Comment: What's actually wrong with just keeping all your files locally - as was the intention right from the start of iTunes? You buy some 'tunes', you have local copies to push to your iPod, etc. iTunes was the 'master' containing songs purchased from Apple, plus all the old CDs you ripped.

Comment: Thanks for the flag and new question - I'm curious what part of this guide isn't in alignment with your question: https://support.apple.com/guide/music-web/play-songs-from-your-library-apdm5cce24ab/web It seems Apple now has precisely what you seek, but perhaps I'm missing something specific in your setup. It says you don't use Windows or macOS but not what you are intending to use.

Comment: @bmike - that's like Spotify, but perhaps worse - you can listen to a minute of anything before being nagged to sign up, but you can't find your own music. It's like having 10,000 radio stations but no hope of finding the one you actually want.

Comment: @Tetsujin not once you sign in - let me add a proper answer to explain / document several items. Please be critical of that answer too - I may not be totally getting "the ask" here.

Comment: You need a subscription though - something I've avoided for a decade or more. If I want to listen to a 'radio' there are thousands, free. I think the OP just wants online access to their own purchases. [That would be pointless for me, because 99% of my iTunes library comes from CDs, not iTunes.]

Comment: @Tetsujin There is _indeed_ nothing "wrong" with that. It's my intent. It's what I currently do. But right now, I'm relying on a dedicated "iTunes terminal" laptop to exfiltrate the physical `.m4a` files, which is obnoxious to deal with when [Amazon MP3 lets me use an arbitrary web browser](https://www.amazon.com/gp/help/customer/display.html?nodeId=G6S668ZHKA8MK6T7) \([as did Google Music](https://www.androidauthority.com/download-music-google-play-music-1118354/), when it existed...\)

Comment: @Tetsujin (of course, as you also mention, CDs exist and do work when necessary—but finding CDs can often be slow, pricey, and extremely hit-or-miss, as well as _guaranteeing_ that the author doesn't see even 1 cent of the purchase price except in the (extremely rare) case that I'm listening to a new release or (rarer still) that the band still has non-retail merch in stock... in any case, this question I've asked today is about songs from the **Apple Music Store**, since I asked it on Apple Stack Exchange. Alternatives exist, but I'm not exactly asking about them; I already know about them.)

Comment: > _It says you don't use Windows or macOS but not what you are intending to use._< Rocky Linux? NetBSD? A PinePhone? An Android phone that doesn't allow non-company-approved apps? There are many, many things I might use. What they all have in common is a **standard web browser** such as Firefox or Chrome, which is why I posed my original question targeting that platform.

Comment: Did you try to play the m4a files *without* iTunes (with another player)? DRM has changed a bit over the years, but I use Roon to play the m4a files I got from iTunes and it works without a hitch.

Comment: @nohillside Yeah, I've never had any issues playing iTunes-purchased M4A files in other players. \(According to a bunch of forum threads I found when googling the issue, that's because Apple stopped applying DRM to the files in 2009, which was a few years before I got my first PC. I assume they're watermarked with my account in some way, but that's no issue as I'm not illegally redistributing them.\) I have enjoyed Apple as a legitimate source of DRM-free music for years; it's only whether I have to use this dedicated **desktop application** to download the files that I was wondering.

Comment: So what do you need iTunes for? Wouldn‘t any browser based audio player with access to your tracks work, or any AAC-capable player on the platform of your choice?

Comment: Looking at your last comment again: Are you looking for an iTunes application-free way to access your library to **listen** to it, or are you looking for a way to **purchase and download** M4A tracks from Apple without using the iTunes application?

Comment: Thanks for the edit. So the whole question could be shortened to "How can I buy and download audio tracks from Apple's Music Store without using iTunes/Apple Music", which has a simple answer: you can't.

Comment: Also: Part of the confusion both in the comments and the existing answer come from the fact that a significant part of the question text focuses on things you **don't** want. You could avoid all that by shortening the question down to the essential part (which probably is one or two short paragraphs only).

Comment: Why not use [WINE](https://www.winehq.org/) to run [iTunes](https://appdb.winehq.org/objectManager.php?sClass=version&iId=31322)? I doubt Apple would care or detect that if you can’t keep or borrow a PC for long enough to do all the purchasing (or periodically purchase what you need).

Answer (score 0):

No web client to purchase and download. Once the files are downloaded, it’s your call how you consume, host and back them up.

- [Buy music from the iTunes Store on your iPhone or iPad](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211330)

Purchase or download requires a Mac or a PC or an iPad or an iPhone and use of Apple’s free to install programs to download - not a web browser.

> - You may access our Services only using Apple’s software, and may not modify or use modified versions of such software.
> - You may not manipulate play counts, downloads, ratings, or reviews via any means — such as (i) using a bot, script, or automated process; or (ii) providing or accepting any kind of compensation or incentive.
> - You may not use any software, device, automated process, or any similar or equivalent manual process to scrape, copy, or perform measurement, analysis, or monitoring of, any portion of the Content or Services.

The [license for purchased music](https://www.apple.com/legal/internet-services/itunes/us/terms.html) also stipulates you have to use Apple apps to consume the files. Whether someone has reverse engineered the protocol or Apple apps or if it’s technically possible, I will leave for others to answer.

Yes for streaming - Apple provides web services at http://music.apple.com to access your entire library on the web. “Your library” is inclusive of all things subscribed or purchased from Apple and songs you brought to the library from another digital purchase or rip/recording traded song. This is a fairly new development and also compliments the availability of Apple Music (or [your iTunes music library when synced up to Apple servers](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204926)) on Android:

- [Use Apple Music with your Android devices](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT210412)
- [Listen to Apple Music on the web and in apps](https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT207717)

Comment: Of course you have to pay them for this service. It’s pretty clear that’s how it works @JamesTheAwesomeDude - you’d have to host your downloaded music yourself if you don’t like apple’s hosting costs and features.  I’ll incorporate the now deleted comments to make this comment and my edits make sense.

Comment: I'm asking if I can **download** the songs—not just vaguely "access" them—I want the actual `.m4a` files that I can back up myself to keep offline copies of forever. Your suggestion would incur an additional 11 USD/month cost, but would it even answer my question as-asked, or is it *only* a suggestion for a streaming service?

Comment: Honestly, I thought you wanted the streaming service @JamesTheAwesomeDude since I read all the things you didn’t want it was the logical conclusion I reached. Here is the purchase option… https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT211330 and I will edit my comment and the answer to make sense after you cleaned up several comments. Thanks for the ping and questions!